# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CSSStyleSheet') heatmap tracking JS error

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager, heatmap

I have integrated the Lucky Orange Heatmap tracking on one of my site, the tracking is integrated using Google tag manager on Window Loaded trigger.
But since we integrated it's showing the following error in the console throughout the site

```
core.js?v=00c647f:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CSSStyleSheet')
    at Object.handler (core.js?v=00c647f:1:30500)
    at Object.start (core.js?v=00c647f:1:33920)
    at core.js?v=00c647f:1:33309
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.observe (core.js?v=00c647f:1:33286)
    at core.js?v=00c647f:1:60461
    at lo.js?site-id=2b5b848f:1:9439
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (lo.js?site-id=2b5b848f:1:9422)
    at n.emit (lo.js?site-id=2b5b848f:1:10178)
```

the error is from https://tools.luckyorange.com/core/core.js JS file

Comment: It does not load the css file the lucky orange script is supposed to deliver. It might be best to contact them directly. You could try experimenting a bit with firing the tag earlier e.g. on dom ready but I doubt it will make a difference.